# How to set constrains in Xcode 6 on login viewcontroller

Tags: swift, storyboard, xcode6, autolayout, constraints

Hi Im creating an app where the first screen that shows I's a log in screen. I'm trying to figure out how to make the logo and title look good on all the iPhone's screen sizes. Right now I'm using "Center horizontally in container" and "Top space to top layout guide". I've searched a lot on this subject but I have not found any tutorial that does what i want to accomplish.

Here's my storyboard scene:

[image: Storyboard]

[image: Preview]

As you can see it looks okay on the 3.5 and 4 inch but on the bigger screens I would like to scale the image a bit larger and move the image down. Also make the space between the image and the text a bit bigger. Thanks!

I tried Para's suggestion and got it working in my storyboard scene but when I run the project it does not work properly. Here's some screenshots:
[image: Storyboard scene]

[image: Simulator screenshot]

And it's the same problem in iPhone 4, 5, 6 and 6 plus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't make a spacing constraint change depending on the height of something.
However, as a spacer, you could use a transparent `UIView`, whose height can be proportional to the View Controller's view height (which, in turn, depends on the phone screen height).
Make sure your `UIImageView` and `UILabel` have a vertical space constraint equal to 0 to your spacers, and you're set.
Just experiment with the spacer's height constraint values to find what suits you.
Here's an example:

[image: Proportional height constraint]

You can do something similar with your `UIImageView`, to make sure it gets bigger on a bigger screen: set its height so that it's proportional to the View Controller's view height, and add an aspect ratio constraint to its width, so that it's 1:1 to the height:

[image: Aspect ratio constraint]

If all goes well, you should have a result that looks like this (the spacers are in green to show you how they grow proportionally to the screen size):

[image: Final result]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Awesome that you took the time to make this answer!

Comment: You're welcome :) if I can help, it's time well spent!

Comment: I got it working in storyboard mode but when i build and run the project it does not work. I've updated my question with some images.

Comment: Please recheck all the constraints you added: do all the views have the correct constraints? From your screenshot, it looks like the "Align Center X" constraints are not working or something like that. If you post all the constraints for each view, we can help. On the other hand, I suppose you've already tried cleaning and rebuilding the project, right?